# How to get notified of textbox focus?

Tags: c++, windows, keyboard, touch

Using a Windows 7 touch device Windows shows this little touch-keyboard indicator (tabing this will bring up the touch on screen keyboard) when you tab/focus a textbox or kind of input field (Notepad etc.).

I want to write an application that gets notified when exactly that happens, a textbox (etc.) gets focused (no matter which application).

Are applications informed about focusing in other applications, do I need to hook something?

Is there a way in doing so in c++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the [SetWinEventHook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373640%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function and specifically the `EVENT_OBJECT_FOCUS` event is what you are looking for.

From the MSDN description:

> An object has received the keyboard focus. The system sends this event for the following user interface elements: list-view control, menu bar, pop-up menu, switch window, tab control, tree view control, and window object. Server applications send this event for their accessible objects.
>
> The hwnd parameter of the WinEventProc callback function identifies the window that receives the keyboard focus.