# How to show notification in c++ when mouse click an editable textbox is focused

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, mfc, event-handling

I've been searching for some days for a solution to this and I couldn't find to much information.

What I am looking for is a small program to show notification when the mouse clicks in text editable fields like text box in windows forms or browser pages is shown.

The only starting point was this [old question from so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8906568/how-to-get-notified-of-textbox-focus?answertab=oldest#tab-top) which leads me to the following:

```
// Global variable.
HWINEVENTHOOK g_hook;

// Initializes COM and sets up the event hook.
//
void InitializeMSAA()
{
    CoInitialize(NULL);
    g_hook = SetWinEventHook(
        EVENT_SYSTEM_MENUSTART, EVENT_SYSTEM_MENUEND,  // Range of events (4 to 5).
        NULL,                                          // Handle to DLL.
        HandleWinEvent,                                // The callback.
        0, 0,              // Process and thread IDs of interest (0 = all)
        WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT | WINEVENT_SKIPOWNPROCESS); // Flags.
}

// Unhooks the event and shuts down COM.
//
void ShutdownMSAA()
{
    UnhookWinEvent(g_hook);
    CoUninitialize();
}

// Callback function that handles events.
//
void CALLBACK HandleWinEvent(HWINEVENTHOOK hook, DWORD event, HWND hwnd, 
                             LONG idObject, LONG idChild, 
                             DWORD dwEventThread, DWORD dwmsEventTime)
{
    IAccessible* pAcc = NULL;
    VARIANT varChild;
    HRESULT hr = AccessibleObjectFromEvent(hwnd, idObject, idChild, &pAcc, &varChild);  
    if ((hr == S_OK) && (pAcc != NULL))
    {
        BSTR bstrName;
        pAcc->get_accName(varChild, &bstrName);
        if (event == EVENT_SYSTEM_MENUSTART) 
        {
            printf("Begin: ");
        }
        else if (event == EVENT_SYSTEM_MENUEND)
        {
            printf("End:   ");
        }
        printf("%S\n", bstrName);
        SysFreeString(bstrName);
        pAcc->Release();
    }
}
```

Do you have any idea about how I can modify this, in order to get notified when a textbox gets focused ? Any explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you understand what the code does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you provided hooks up on menu open and close events `EVENT_SYSTEM_MENUSTART`, and `EVENT_SYSTEM_MENUEND`.

You should try using `EVENT_OBJECT_FOCUS` (and maybe `EVENT_OBJECT_SELECT` instead in your `SetWinEventHook` and `HandleWinEvent`.

```
void CALLBACK HandleWinEvent(HWINEVENTHOOK hook, DWORD event, HWND hwnd, 
                             LONG idObject, LONG idChild, 
                             DWORD dwEventThread, DWORD dwmsEventTime)
{
    IAccessible* pAcc = NULL;
    VARIANT varChild;
    HRESULT hr = AccessibleObjectFromEvent(hwnd, idObject, idChild, &pAcc, &varChild);  
    BSTR bstrName;
    pAcc->get_accName(varChild, &bstrName);

    if (event == EVENT_OBJECT_FOCUS || event == EVENT_OBJECT_SELECTION) 
    {
        printf("%S\n", bstrName);
    }       
}

void InitializeMSAA()
{
    CoInitialize(NULL);
    g_hook = SetWinEventHook(
        EVENT_OBJECT_FOCUS, EVENT_OBJECT_SELECTION,
        NULL,                                          // Handle to DLL.
        HandleWinEvent,                                // The callback.
        0, 0,              // Process and thread IDs of interest (0 = all)
        WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT | WINEVENT_SKIPOWNPROCESS); // Flags.
}
```

Look at the documentation for the list of available events:

[SetWinEventHook function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373640.aspx)

[Event Constants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318066.aspx)

Comment: I know. I've tried what you suggested but I didn't come with a working solution because I didn't find any related infos about how should I use `EVENT_OBJECT_FOCUS`